# How can I get reference a dynamically generated element so I can remove it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I'm trying to make a page that generates a thumbnail from uploading an image and that can delete it by clicking a tag.

I suppose I need a parameter on each dynamic element, so I can have a reference to it, in order to remove it.

Im my current implementation, `onclick` function doesn't work properly, as it is executed when the image is uploaded, not when clicked.

I also tried this:

```
$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});
```

But it returns `[object object]`, not the actual parameter that can identify the image.

Here's my code:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var filelist;

var storeimg = new Array();

$("#fileupload").on("change", function handleImgFileSelect(e) {
  var ufiles = e.target.files;
  var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(ufiles);

  var reg = /(.*?)\/(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$/;

  filesArr.forEach(function (f) {
    if (!f.type.match(reg)) {
      alert("only image extensions are allowed");
      document.getElementById("fileupload").value = "";
      return;
    }

    storeimg.push(f);
    console.log('foundfile=' + f.name);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $(".uploadedList").append('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width = "50px" height = "50px" class = "uploadedimg"><small class="deleteimg" style="cursor: pointer" onclick=' + deleteFnc(f.name) + '>ClickHereToRemoveIMG</small>');
    }
  });

});

function deleteFnc(fname) {
  window.alert(fname);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submitform">
  <input type="text" id="submitReviewWriter" name="reviews" class="form-control" placeholder="Comment">
  <div class="text-center">
    <input type='file' id='fileupload' name="fileupload[]" multiple="multiple" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />

    <div id="uploadedList" class='uploadedList'></div>
    <button id="submitReview" type="submit" class="btn btn-main text-center">submitComment</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to bind the `onclick` function **via jQuery** on the `<small>` element, just after you create it, instead of trying bind the event attribute as a string.

Also, you can put both the `<img>` and the `<small>` inside a `<span>`, so you can delete both together (by calling [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) and then [`.remove()`](https://api.jquery.com/remove/))

```
reader.onload = function (e) {
  var img = $('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="50px" height="50px" class="uploadedimg">');
  var del = $('<small class="deleteimg" style="cursor: pointer">ClickHereToRemoveIMG</small>');
  var spn = $('<span></span>').append(img).append(del)
  $(".uploadedList").append(spn);
  del.click(function() {  
      var clicked = $(this);
      clicked.parent().remove()
  });
}
```

```js
var formData = new FormData();
var filelist;

var storeimg = new Array();

$("#fileupload").on("change", function handleImgFileSelect(e) {
  var ufiles = e.target.files;
  var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(ufiles);

  var reg = /(.*?)\/(jpg|jpeg|png|bmp)$/;

  filesArr.forEach(function (f) {
    if (!f.type.match(reg)) {
      alert("only image extensions are allowed");
      document.getElementById("fileupload").value = "";
      return;
    }

    storeimg.push(f);
    console.log('foundfile=' + f.name);
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      var img = $('<img src="' + e.target.result + '" width="50px" height="50px" class="uploadedimg">');
      var del = $('<small class="deleteimg" style="cursor: pointer">ClickHereToRemoveIMG</small>');
      var spn = $('<span></span>').append(img).append(del)
      $(".uploadedList").append(spn);
      del.click(function() {  
          var clicked = $(this);
          clicked.parent().remove()
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="submitform">
    <input type="text" id="submitReviewWriter" name="reviews"
    class="form-control" placeholder="Comment">
<div class="text-center">
<input type='file' id='fileupload' name="fileupload[]" multiple="multiple" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" />

    <div id="uploadedList" class='uploadedList'></div>
    <button id="submitReview" type="submit"
                class="btn btn-main text-center">submitComment</button>
    </div>
</form>
```